# titleview dissapears when a subview is added?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, uitapgesturerecognizer, titleview

This is new to me so forgive me if I'm not asking the right question.

I'm following a tutorial where we are creating a few subviews inside of a titleview for the navigation bar so that a picture and username displays. When I create the intial titleview with a red background, it shows up as expected. However, when I add a container subview to place the text and image, the red titleview disappears. I finished the tutorial and the text shows up in the right place, but it doesn't allow me to add a tap gesture, since the titleview isn't there anymore to tap?

I'll add my code for this function- hopefully there's a stupid mistake that I'm missing.

```
func setupNavBarWithUser(user: User) {

    let titleView = UIView()
    titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 35)
    titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    titleView.addSubview(containerView)

    let profileImageView = UIImageView()
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
    }

    containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)

    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true

    let nameLabel = UILabel()


    containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)

    nameLabel.text = user.name
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController)))
    titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: after rendering what is the height and width of the container view

Comment: The container view isn't showing dimensions either. The video is instructing us to do this so that the picture and text will stay centered.

Comment: Seems like you have to set constraints for your container view hight and width

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that and the container view shows up in the right spot, but the titleview is still missing and is preventing the tapgesture. Does it have something to do with the fact that it was created with a CGRect instead of anchors?

Comment: do you know how to use debug view hierarchy in xcode ?

Comment: Not really, but I see the layers and the label/image are there, as is the container view. I don't see the titleview anywhere. In the sidebar, the UIView that they are nested in has an exclamation point that says 'Position and size are ambiguous'

Comment: Can you share the project. I can check if you want !

Comment: That would be great- does this work? https://github.com/seeshaughnessy/gameofchats

Comment: Can you include your pod files because I cant compile this

Comment: Oops sorry... should be updated

Comment: Never mind, I created the required pod files, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace setupNavBarWithUser method with this:

```
func setupNavBarWithUser(user: User) {

        let titleView = UIView()
        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 45)
        titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

        titleView.addSubview(containerView)

        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        let profileImageView = UIImageView()
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
            profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
        }

        containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)

        profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true

        let nameLabel = UILabel()

        containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)

        nameLabel.text = user.name
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true


        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

        titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController)))
        titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }
```

You can compare the codes. As you can see you have to add subview in a proper order to set your constraints.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!